# error: Multiple commands produce, IOS build error flutter in Mac Mini M1

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, flutter-dependencies, apple-m1

```
error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btwffzljdlaqbxbugphdlprtatcr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/develop/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework':

1) Target 'Reachability' has create directory command with output '/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btwffzljdlaqbxbugphdlprtatcr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/develop/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'

2) Target 'ReachabilitySwift' has create directory command with output '/Users/***/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-btwffzljdlaqbxbugphdlprtatcr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/develop/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/Reachability.framework'
```

Getting this error while generating build-in IOS.